# How can I logout from Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion

There is no "log out" anywhere on the page.  I have no idea how to log out.

I cannot ask this question on Politics Meta because for this I need a reputation of 5.

Comment: its under the stack exchange menu drop down

Comment: Have you tried this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NiIGEg473PA

Answer (score 3):

at the top left, click on the box that says "stack exchange", and that will open a menu

at the top right of that menu will be a link to "log out"

[image]